# Exercise from Rotman, direct limit of quotient modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

Suppose $$0 \to U \to V \to V/U \to 0$$ is an exact sequence of left $R$-modules.

Let $\lbrace U_i, \alpha^{i}_j\rbrace$ be a direct sequence of submodules of $U$, where $$\alpha^{i}_j : U_i \to U_j \ \ \ \ i \leq j$$ is the inclusion. Moreover we have $$U = \underrightarrow{\lim} U_i.$$

Then we see that $\lbrace V/U_i, e^{i}_j\rbrace$ with $$e^{i}_j : V/U_i \to V/U_j \ \ \ \ i \leq j$$ $$v + U_i \to v + U_j$$ is a direct system.

I have to show that $\underrightarrow{\lim}V/U_i \cong V/U$.

I don't know how to define a map from $V/U$ to another cocone over $\lbrace V/U_i, e^{i}_j\rbrace$, any hint ?

Comment: It's not true without extra assumptions. My guess is that you're supposed to assume that $U=\underrightarrow{\lim}(U_i)$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard; Yes sorry, I have forgotten a point; I modified the question

Comment: @JeremyRickard: Now do you know the answer ?

Comment: Has the book covered the theorem that a direct limit of short exact sequences of modules is a short exact sequence by this point? If so, consider the short exact sequences $0\to U_i\to V\to V/U_i\to 0$.

Comment: @WLOG Could you please write where is this exercise in Rotman?

Comment: @magma: Yes, Rotman, An introduction to homological algebra, exercise 5.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Say we have a cocone $\left(V/U_i\overset{g_i}\to W\right)_i$. Then consider the canonical map $\varphi:V\to V/U_i\to W$. By the cocone property, it doesn't depend on $i$, and show that $U\le \ker\varphi$.

Comment: I don't see why $U \subseteq \ker \phi $

Comment: can you explain this point ?

Comment: Consider the cocone ${\bf c}:=\big( U_i\to V \big)_i$, its limit is the inclusion $U\hookrightarrow V$, then consider the composite $\varphi\circ{\bf c}$: all its arrows are *zero*, and by the limit property, it factors through $U\to V\overset{\varphi}\to W$.

Comment: Or, interpreting all modules $U_i$ *within* $V$, if the system $U_i$ is directed, then we have $\underrightarrow\lim U_i\ =\ \bigcup_i U_i$.